# Запрос в базу Mysql, или как ее грамотно построить

Tags: ajax, php, sql-server

Как правильно сделать базу?

Создал базу mysql:

```
id     floor cabinet    name           path
1      2      4      Kyocera 2523   URL
```

Суть такая: у нас здание, состоящее из 4 этажей, на каждом этаже кабинеты, в каждом кабинете по несколько принтеров. Хочу реализовать веб-морду, через которую юзер сможет  выбирать нужный ему принтер и установить драйвера.

Так вот, он заходит и выбирает из выпадающего меню этаж и в соседнее выпадающее меню прогружаются все кабинеты, которые есть на этом этаже, после выбора кабинета в соседнее выпадающее меню грузятся принтера, которые есть в этом кабинете, а лишь затем ссылка на скрипт, запустив который пользователь сможет себе установить  этот принтер.

Я слаб в  программировании, но есть прогресс.
Вопрос: правильно ли я построил базу данных? Если да, то как писать запрос в нее для выборки кабинетов по этажу?

Заранее спасибо! Всех люблю и ценю!

Кстати, при грамотном подходе можно было бы реализовать онлайн коммерческий продукт. Если кого-то заденет эта идея, можем пообщаться. )

Comment: так как выборку делать, исходя по этажу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Таблица в принципе норм, тут главное определится, по чем выбор принтеров делать (этаж или по конкретной модели принтера), и, самое главное, еще нужно и админ часть делать, чтоб можно было добавлять принтера, редактировать скрипты и т.д.

Comment: Запрос сделал таким: 

    $sql="SELECT * FROM printers WHERE floor = '".$q."'";

Comment: И все, выборка по этажу работает.

Answer (score 3):

Структура таблицы вполне норм. Но, кроме неё, рекомендую создать вторую таблицу printers (

```
id |    name     | path
 1 | Kyocera 2523|  setupK2523
 2 | HP LJ p1120 |  setupHPLJp1120
```

А в первой таблице вместо названия принтера вставлять id из второй таблицы.

```
id | floor | cabinet | printerID          
 1 |   2   |   4     |    1
 2 |   1   |   5     |    1
 3 |   1   |   4     |    2
```

В ситуации, когда у Вас будет несколько одинаковых принтеров, не потребуется дублировать записи.
Запрос для выборки принтеров, находящихся в комнате:

```
 select 
       printers.name,printers.path
    from
       printers 
       inner join table on (printers.id = table.printerID)
    where
       table.floor = '$floor' and table.cabinet = '$cabinet'
```

Для построения админки такая схема тоже будет удобней. Отдельно добавляются принтеры, и отдельно для каждого кабинета можно добавить из списка принтер. В ситуации, когда какой-то из принтеров будет, к примеру, забран на ремонт, то при возврате не потребуется создавать новую запись, прописывая ручками данные о нём.